Making the BLE (iBeacon mode) connectable on a STM32WB55 board
I'm currently working on a STM32WB55 board and I'm trying to make the BLE (iBeacon mode) connectable.
Actually, the porpuse is to send a data frame via BLE and be able to go back and modify some fields of the frame, in instance the minorID and the TxPower_Level.
I've successfully configured the BLE in ibeacon mode, receiving the frame (uuid, minor,major). The specifications require us to enter a code to connect and change certain values. But that's where I run into a problem. if I try to change the code to connect, the app on my phone automatically ejects me. do you know if what I'm trying to do is possible? if not, do I have to switch to template mode to configure the BLE in ibeacon (if possible) and be able to change the parameters concerned? if so, how do I go about it?
